# Opencart 2.0 403 Forbidden Access after Setting Save in Admin

Tags: opencart, settings

I just install a clean version (with a new database) of `opencart 2.0`, then I go to the admin page, Setting then just open and save the configuration (no changes made) and I get the following error:

403
Forbidden

Access to this resource on the server is denied!

Am checking server folder permissions on the server it is `755`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finlay i got the solution, it is based on `cPanel` issues.

**Solutions for following steps:**

**Step 1:**

Login your `cPanel`.

**Step 2:**

Find `ModSecurity`.

[image]

**Step 3:**

Choose your domain and `disable` `ModSecurity`.

**Step 4:**

Clear the History and try it again.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

**Your hosting company probably blacklisted your IP**

(I'm assuming it's not on your localhost)

I used to have this issue too and it only occurred on the Admin Settings page after saving. Changing permissions of every *folder and file* didn't fix it.

After about a year of searching for a fix and having to manually make edits directly to my database, I contacted my hosting company about it and they said my IP was blacklisted. All they had to do was allow a set of IP addresses and I haven't had the issue ever since.

So contact your hosting company about it. And be as specific as possible with them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i will update and tell you

Comment: I got the `IP` where i want to paste in `database`

Comment: You don't need to paste the IP anywhere. All I did was ask them,  "Hi guys, I keep getting a 403 Forbidden error when I click save on the following page: [insert URL]. Can you please check it?"